# New Order Email Template for each Product type in Magento

Tags: orders, email-templates, product-type

I wanted customization.I have Simple,Downladable and Virtual Products in my Magento Store and I need three New order email template one for each product type.

Like if my customer order virtual product i need to send virtual product's new order email template in the email.similarly for the simple and the Downloadable.

I needed this customization.Is it Possible in Magento.

Please Help Me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This should be fairly simple.

1> Create the different transactional email templates from Admin: `System > Transactional Emails > Add New Template`
REF: http://go.magento.com/support/kb/entry/name/customizing-transactional-emails/

2> Assign the new email templates to the different product types. For this you can use system configuration file (system.xml) of your custom module. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <sales_email>
            <groups>
                <order>
                    <fields>
                        <custom_email_simple translate="label">
                            <label>Custom Email Template (Simple)</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_email_template</source_model>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </custom_email_simple>
                        <custom_email_virtual translate="label">
                            <label>Custom Email Template (Virtual)</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_email_template</source_model>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </custom_email_virtual>
                        ...
                    </fields>
                </order>
            </groups>
        </sales_email>
    </sections>
</config>
```

3> Rewrite the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::sendNewOrderEmail()` method
And replace the following portion of the code:

```
// Retrieve corresponding email template id and customer name
if ($this->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
    $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_GUEST_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
    $customerName = $this->getBillingAddress()->getName();
} else {
    $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
    $customerName = $this->getCustomerName();
}
```

by:

```
// loop over all the quote items
// and find the getTypeId() of that product
// but note the case of multiple products in an order with different types
$orderItems = $this->getAllVisibleItems();
$productTypes = array();
foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
    $productTypes[] = $product->getTypeId();
}
$productType = array_pop($productTypes);

// Retrieve corresponding email template id and customer name
if ($this->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
     $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_GUEST_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
     $customerName = $this->getBillingAddress()->getName();
 } else {
     //here we are tweaking only for customers, similarly you can do it for guest users
     ##$templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
     $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig('sales_email/order/custom_email_' . $productType), $storeId;
     $customerName = $this->getCustomerName();
 }
```

Hope this gives you some idea.